# Передача данных из JSON файла в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Здраствуйте!
Есть JSON файлик с данными

```json
{
    "stats": [
        {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "8835",
            "capacity": 6
        },
        {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "8834",
            "capacity": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

как можно импортировать его в JavaScript, для построение графиков?
Прошу не судить строго и не кидать в меня тапком, так как в етом деле я новичок!
Спасибо!

Comment: каких именно графиков? посмотрите highcharts к примеру

Comment: Спасибо, Zhihar, но я хотел бы узнать, как я могу получить данные с своего JSON файла, дла построение графиков. С библиотеками для построение всё понятно, но вот как данные получить, для меня ето тёмный лес)))

Comment: Вам стоит уточнить, где будет исполняться JavaScript — в браузере или Node.js.

Comment: vsemozhebuty, в браузере.

Comment: Если JSON на сервере, можно посмотреть варианты тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346563/loading-local-json-file

Answer (score 2):

```
JSON.stringify(object) // obj => json
JSON.parse(json) // json => obj
```

они имеют второй аргумент это функция с помощью которой можно более детально преобразовать

импортировать по запросу например fetch()

Comment: Спасибо огромное!))) Всё заработало))))

Comment: @СвятославГранатир незачто)

Comment: @СвятославГранатир отметь как ответ, пожалуйтса.